# Problems with modifying props directly in vuejs vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, properties, vuex, v-model

I'm working in this web app, trying to build a searchbar filter which allows me to do my own query from writing whatever I want (if the API contains the data), but throws me always the same error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "Search".

I was looking on some of your responses, trying to apply them to my case, but them gives me a massive error, turned to worst, here is part of my code, my original one:

```
  <v-container>
    <input class='input'
        @input='sendingSelfSearch'
      placeholder="write words for search"
      type="text"
      v-model="Search"
    />
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",

  props: {
      SearchBar:Object,
      Search:String
  },

  methods:{
      sendingSelfSearch(){
          this.$emit('receivingSelfSearch',this.Search)
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

And in this second part I'm receiving that component from 'Search' (component) to 'Home' (view):

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
              <img class='body' src='../assets/alli.jpg'/>
              <SearchBar @receivingSelfSearch='autoSearch' v-bind:Search='Search'></SearchBar>... 
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
import Filters from '../components/Filters.vue'
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Filters,
    SearchBar
  },
  data(){
    return {
       listCountries:'',
       listEvents:'',
       listModalities:'',
       Search:'',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    autoSearch(text){
       this.Search=text
    },
  },
  computed:{
       autoSearchFilter(){
          some code
  }
```

...the result of the query shows, but at same time I have this error in the devtool console, thus despite of being working is not 'correct' somehow.
Any suggestions regarding this code where I should improve please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because you are modifying `Search` prop by using `v-model` on your input (`SearchBar` component)

Do this instead:

```js
<v-container>
    <input class='input'
      placeholder="write words for search"
      type="text"
      v-model="searchPhrase"
    />
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",

  props: {
      Search: String
  },
  computed: {
    searchPhrase: {
      get() { return this.Search }
      set(val) { this.$emit('receivingSelfSearch', val) }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

How using computed property for `v-model` works:

1. Child receives prop `Search` from the parent (parent owns the data - it has `Search` in `data()`)
2. When the Child is rendering and needs initial value for the input, it calls getter (`get()` method) which returns value of `Search` prop
3. When user changes content of input, Vue will do something like `searchPhrase = new value`, which in turn calls setter
4. Setter emits the event with new value as an event payload
5. Parent listener gets a new value and assign it into the `Search` data variable (`@receivingSelfSearch='autoSearch'`)
6. Vue detects the `Search` is changed and update Child component, updating `Search` prop inside the Child to a new value

Comment: but then shall i cancel my former "this.$emit('receivingSelfSearch',this.Search)" at all?

Comment: would i have to receive that emit in my view  using val instead of search, binding it (val) to the data return Search i already declared in that instance?

Comment: Use my code in your `SearchBar` component and leave parent component as is (listening for `receivingSelfSearch` event and assigning new value into `Search` data prop).

Comment: i just @input=searchPhrase , i mean the same v- modeled computed method in order to be able to pass it to my home view , but keeps giving me error...now says:Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"...though still the search bar gives me results on the query

Comment: template>
  <v-container>
    <input class='input'
        @input='sendingSelfSearch'
      placeholder="write words for search"
      type="text"
      v-model="sendingSelfSearch"
    />
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>

Comment: You don't need `@input` on input when you have `v-model`. __Use my code as is!__

Comment: <script>
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",
  props: {
      SearchBar:Object,
      Search:String
  },
//   methods:{
//       sendingSelfSearch(){
//           this.$emit('receivingSelfSearch',this.Search)
//       }
//   },
  computed:{
     sendingSelfSearch:{
         get(){
             return this.Search
         },
         set(val){ this.$emit('receivingSelfSearch', val) }
     },
  }
};
</script>

Comment: just send to you what iadjust in the code having in mind your explanation, but keeps giving me error